# Retrieve list elements using variable containing list of indices python

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to use a variable `flist` consisting of a list of indices to retrieve the elements from `features` list.

```
flist = [1, 3, 7]

features = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
```

Desired output:

```
['b', 'd', 'h']
```

Is there a way of retrieving the elements from `features` using `flist` directly? For example, when I try `features[flist[i] for i in range(0,len(flist))]` I get an 'invalid syntax' error.

Thanks

Comment: Note, the linked duplicate is actually asking for *alternatives* to something like `[features[i] for i in flist]`, but that is probably the cleanest way

Answer (score 1):

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']

idxs = [1, 3, 7]

print ([l[i] for i in idxs])
```

Output:

```
['b', 'd', 'h']
```

Just use a simple list comprehension to make a list of elements from `l` present at an index contained in `idxs`.